# Rails 4 - partial rendered with update.js.erb not showing updated values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

On the account settings page for my Rails app I am trying to use Ajax to have the displayed users settings info updated after the update form is submitted. Right now when I submit the form the database gets updated and the _account_settings.html.erb partial appears to get re-rendered, but the partial doesn't show the updated information. For example, say the users name is "John Doe" and he clicks the '#edit_name' link. This renders the _name_form.html.erb which he can use to change his name. When he changes his name and submits the form, let's say he changes it to "Joe Blow", the form disappears and the 'Name: <%= current_user.name %> - click to edit' shows up again but the name is still "John Doe"  even though the name in the DB is now "Joe Blow". If I refresh the page the name now appears as "Joe Blow". I am using devise and made a custom registrations controller to allow the user to update certain attributes without entering a password (name still requires the current password). I used [this code provided by the devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) and simply added

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to edit_user_registration_path }
    format.js
end
```

to the end of the 'if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)' block in the above link. Any ideas as to why the re-rendered partial isn't showing the updated user information?

```
edit.html.erb
<h1>Account Settings</h1>
<div id="account_settings_container">
    <%= render 'account_settings' %>
</div>


_account_settings.html.erb
<div class="user-attribute-container">
    <%= link_to "#", class: "edit-attribute", id: "edit_name", remote: true do %>
        <p>Name: <%= current_user.name %> - click to edit</p>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div class="user-attribute-container">
    <%= link_to "#", class: "edit-attribute", id: "edit_email", remote: true do %>
        <p>Email: <%= current_user.email %> - click to edit</p>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div class="user-attribute-container">
    <%= link_to "#", class: "edit-attribute", id: "edit_password", remote: true do %>
        <p>Password: click to edit your password</p>
    <% end %>
</div>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
    $("#edit_name").click(function() {
        $(this).hide().after("<%= escape_javascript(render('name_form')) %>");
    });
    $("#edit_email").click(function() {
        $(this).hide().after("<%= escape_javascript(render('email_form')) %>");
    });
    $("#edit_password").click(function() {
        $(this).hide().after("<%= escape_javascript(render('password_form')) %>");
    });
<% end %>


_name_form.html.erb (the email and password form partials have :email, :password & :password_confirmation instead of :name, otherwise they're the same)
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :method => :put, :html => { id: "edit_user_name" }, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :password_field, "Password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :current_password %>

    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>


update.js.erb
$("#account_settings_container").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('account_settings')) %>");
```

**From the log file:**

```
Started PUT "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-09 15:01:21 -0700<br>
Processing by RegistrationsController#update as JS<br>
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"name"=>"Joe Blow", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}<br>
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 14 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m<br>
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 14]]<br>
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m<br>
  [1m[35mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "name" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = 14  [["name", "Joe Blow"], ["updated_at", Mon, 09 Jun 2014 15:01:21 PDT -07:00]]<br>
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m<br>
  Rendered registrations/_name_form.html.erb (15.6ms)<br>
  Rendered registrations/_email_form.html.erb (0.0ms)<br>
  Rendered registrations/_password_form.html.erb (15.6ms)<br>
  Rendered registrations/_account_settings.html.erb (46.9ms)<br>
  Rendered registrations/update.js.erb (46.9ms)<br>
Completed 200 OK in 219ms (Views: 78.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Custom devise registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    def update
        @user = User.find(current_user.id)

        successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
          @user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
        else
            # remove the virtual current_password attribute
            # update_without_password doesn't know how to ignore it
            params[:user].delete(:current_password)
            @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
        end

        if successfully_updated
            # sign_in @user, :bypass => true
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html { redirect_to edit_user_registration_path }
                format.js
            end
        else
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html { render "edit" }
                format.js
            end
        end
    end

    private

    def needs_password?(user, params)
        user.email != params[:user][:email] || params[:user][:password].present? || user.name != params[:user][:name] 
    end
 end
```

Comment: I would try `@user.update_attributes(account_update_params)` by itself and then your if block could be `if @user.save ...`.  I think what is happening is that your changes are being saved to the database but not until after the method is finished executed which includes the rerender of the partial.

Comment: What does registrations/update.js.erb look like?

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it. One thing I noticed is that after clicking update the `<p>Name: <%= current_user.name %> - click to edit</p>` section of _account_settings.html.erb has the old name but the value of the name input tag that comes from the javascript tag in the same partial has the updated name.

Comment: @Swards - `$("#account_settings_container").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('account_settings')) %>");`

Comment: @sc_12_19 are you able to alert from your update.js.erb file?

Comment: Yes, if I put an alert in the update.js.erb file it shows up when I submit the form.

Comment: After tinkering around with it some more I noticed that if I update an attribute (say the user's name) and hit submit the old value still shows. But if I update another attribute (say the user's email) and submit the form then the old email will still show but now the new name shows. So it seems like what Jake said above might be true, although his suggestion didn't seem to fix the problem. EDIT: I updated the original post to include the code for the custom devise registrations controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current_user is generated by Devise using a before_filter. So the object returned, will be the user as it was before that action method was called. You need to use the @user object which is the user object that is modified by the action method.

So for example:

```
<p>Name: <%= @user.name %> - click to edit</p>
```